# Electron build commands to generate Windows 10 & 11 exe file

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

i am new to Electron so I went through all the guick start guides, examples and tutorials. I have build a simple Website that i need to convert with Electron and publish as a Windows exe file.

As i am working on MacOS, builds for MacOS are running, all fine.
For Windows i´ve installed mono and wine and found a great tutorial [here](https://stevenklambert.com/writing/comprehensive-guide-building-packaging-electron-app/)

When using **electron-packager** with the following command, it generates an exe which runs **only on Windows 10** - but not Windows 11. There is no error message, just nothing opens.

```
"npx electron-packager . <appname> --platform=darwin,linux,win32 --arch=ia32,x64 --icon=path/to/icons/dir"
```

When using **electron-builder** with the following command, it generates an exe which runs **only on Windows 11** - but not Windows 10. There is no error message, just nothing opens.

```
electron-builder -mwl
```

Can anybody help me out, what´s the right command/parameter to generate one .exe for both platforms? Cannot find a solution on my own after 3-4 hours search, trial & error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Only runs on..." Aha, what's the error message or the behaviour you're getting? Please [edit] your question to include these details. Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderLeithner for your comment. Edit done. There is no error message. It just doesn´t open ;( Just wanted to ask which parameter the Electron pros are using to export from Mac for Windows 10 & 11. Thanks

Comment: Why are you including ia32 (Windows 32bit) in your --arch options?  Since Electron is html/css/js, and by its very nature designed to be cross platform, what are you using wine/mono for?  Aside:  even though "win32" includes "32", it does not mean 32 bit.  It is just a name for the Window platform.  Maybe you should build one platform/arch at a time for testing?

Comment: Thanks @exception for taking your time to answer. In the tutorials its mentioned, that when working on MacOS, i need to install mono and wine for the building process for windows applications. Regarding your idea of trying each platform at a time: sure. But i didn´t see an overview of all possible --arch and --platform parameters. Do you have an overview within the docs? Didnt find anything.

Comment: There is a usage.txt file link on the electron-packager github page:  https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/main/usage.txt.  In any event, since you are building for Windows 10/11 the options should be:  --platform=win32  --arch=x64

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks @exception. That was helpful! Also i found this useful link for more details: https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/#supported-platforms Again, thank you very much!!